# Vector vs. Data frame in R

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

What is the difference between a vector and a data frame in R? Under what circumstances vectors should be converted to data frames?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A vector has 1 dimension while a data frame has 2. I can't think of a good reason to convert a single vector into a data frame. That question generally arises when you have multiple vectors.

A better question is what is the difference between a data frame and a matrix: a data frame can have different data types for each column, while a matrix is all one data type. Behind the scenes, a data frame is really a list with equal length vectors at each index.

Comment: I was just going to ask you the difference between matrices and data frames. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 5):

Another good point to note is that when running code, operations on matrixes are (most of the time) much faster then on data frames.

Tal

Comment: And another point is that `data.frame` can hold different data types (dates, numbers, factors) and `matrix` only one type.